# Expected token RPAREN but got Token(STAR,*,180,*) in def isConnected = (ss: Site*) => ??? with Scala 2.11.0-M8

Tags: scala

Why does the following function object give me a compilation error in Scala **2.11.0-M8**?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def isConnected = (ss: String*) => true
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but identifier found.
       def isConnected = (ss: String*) => true
                                    ^
```

When I change it to a method it works fine.

```
scala> def isConnected(ss: String*) = true
isConnected: (ss: String*)Boolean
```

Is a variable argument function object possible in Scala? Is this a function object at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala's function literal syntax (e.g. `(i: Int) => i + 1`) is just sugar for defining instances of some `FunctionN`, where the `N` indicates the (fixed) number of arguments. So for example the following are equivalent:

```
val f1 = (i: Int) => i + 1
val f2 = new Function1[Int, Int] { def apply(i: Int) = i + 1 }
```

The standard library provides `Function0` through `Function22`, but doesn't include any idea of a `Function*` object with a variable number of arguments, and if you try to eta-expand a method with a variable number of arguments you'll get a `Function1[Seq[A], B]`:

```
scala> isConnected _
res0: Seq[String] => Boolean = <function1>
```

Note that you can still define an object with a varargs `apply`:

```
object isConnected {
  def apply(ss: String*) = true
}
```

You can use this like a varargs function object—you still get the `isConnected(...)` syntactic sugar, for example—but it's not technically an instance of any `FunctionWhatever` trait, and you don't get the function literal syntactic sugar.